# How to correct already "added to index" files in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

My question is how to correct files which I already added to index:

1. git init
2. git add index.html

Let's say I want to commit some changes in my index.html. How to do that?

Comment: just call `git add` again?

Comment: You can `git add` as many times as you want. `git commit` makes it final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index does not just *list* files, it actually *contains copies of* files.  This thing—this index, or staging area, or cache—holds a copy of *every* file, except for any files you specifically want to be *missing* in the commit.  The thing is so important that it has these three names.  (Or, perhaps, the first name used for it was so bad that it grew a couple of extra names.  Either way it now has these three names.)

Git stores commits as snapshots.  Each commit has a copy of *all* of your files—all of the files that were in the index, that is, at the time you ran `git commit`.  They're stored in a special, frozen/read-only, compressed, Git-only format.  That's fine for archives, but useless for getting work done.  Remember that for the next few bits.

When you tell Git `git checkout master`, you're telling Git: *Find the commit identified by the name `master`.  Copy those files into your index, then copy them from your index to my work-tree so that I can see the files and work on them.*  In your work-tree, the files are normal.  You can use them.  Your computer can use them.  You can *change* them, rename them, remove them, whatever you want.

When you tell Git `git add somefile`, you're telling Git: *Copy the file `somefile` from my work-tree, where I can see it and work on it, into your index so that it's ready to go into the next commit.*  The copy that's in the index is in the special Git-only format, but—until you *commit* it anyway—it's not *frozen*.  It's just *ready to freeze*.

When you tell Git `git rm somefile`, you're telling Git: *Remove the file `somefile` from my index and from my work-tree.*  If you use `--cached`, as in `git rm --cached somefile`, you tell Git to remove it from the index, but leave it alone in the work-tree.

When you tell Git `git commit`, you're telling Git: *Take all the files that are in the index right now.  Freeze them into a new commit.*  Whatever is in the index *then*, that's what's in your new commit.  Whatever *isn't* in the index, that's *not* in your new commit.  So your new commit is a snapshot.  The index contains the *proposed next snapshot*.  You can change it around as much as you like, at any time: `git add` copies files into it, replacing the old one or making a new one depending on whether there was one of that name in there before.  Arrange—or "stage", hence the name "staging area"—the files as you like, then use `git commit` to freeze them into a snapshot.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to hear:) One more question: is _git add_ also snapshot in sense of do I need to _git add_ again some file which is already added to index but I want to commit some changes on it(or to git rm --cached and when commit changes again git add)? Many thanks

Comment: Since `git add` *copies* the current work-tree file into the index, you do in fact have a ready-to-save copy of that file *as of the time you ran `git add`*. If you have changed it *again* since then, the question becomes: do you want to save-forever the *current* index copy, or do you want to *replace* the index copy with *yet another* copy? Commit will save-forever whatever is in the index now. Thinks of the commits as snapshots, and the index copies as *temporary copies*. Your current index and work-tree won't appear in any *other* clone you make; they're *not* saved permanently.

Comment: To *see* what's in the index (try this in a small repository because a big one will have so many files it will be overwhelming) use `git ls-files --stage`. To see *a* file that's in the index, use `git show :<name>`. Compare that to `git show HEAD:<name>`, which shows you what's in the current *commit*. Make a new empty repository, create a file named `README`, add it, and commit it. Then change it and run `git add`. Change it again. Now do `git show HEAD:README`, then `git show :README`. Run `git add README` again and try `git show :README` again.